# Meal Calendar - Database Schema - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I want to build a meal package, where I can design meals and associate them to different meals throughout the week. (breakfast or dinner from 1-7 for 7 days)

My initial thought was a many-to-many relationship

**Plan A** (Don't think it'll work)

Tables: (for example)

```
meals:
  id
  name

package:
  id:
  name:

meal_package:
  meal_id
  package_id
  calendar_code: (enum of {1D, 2D .. 7D, 1B, 2B .. 7B})
```

Classes: (as an example)

```
class Meal extends Model {
    public function packages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Package::class)->withPivot('calendar_code');
    }
}

class Package extends Model {
    public function meals() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Meal::class)->withPivot('calendar_code');
    }
}
```

but, attaching and detaching these will be more difficult.. a typical many-to-many wouldn't have the same 2 entities linked to each other more than once, would they?

I'm using Laravel 5.4..

I am open to suggestions as for other ways to approach this..

My other thought was to change it like this.

**Plan B** (Don't think it's optimal..)

Tables: (for example)

```
meals:
  id
  name

package:
  id:
  name:

meal_package:
  meal_id
  package_id
  calendar_code: (enum of {1D, 2D .. 7D, 1B, 2B .. 7B})
```

Classes: (as an example)

```
class Meal extends Model {
    public function package() {
        return $this->hasMany(Package::class);
    }
}

class Package extends Model {

    public function d1_meal() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Meal::class);
    }

    public function d2_meal() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Meal::class);
    }

    ...

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've made a little ERD for you.

First, maybe next time try to use better terms:

*I want to build a meal package, where I can design meals and associate them to different meals throughout the week*

Would've been better translated to:

*I want to have a menu that contains multiple meals that are reusable throughout the week.*

Terminology is very important when it comes to business processes and even more important in coding.

It makes coding way better to understand.

A good book on that is : *'Clean Coding by Robert Cecil Martin'*

Now to the matter in question:

[image]

- Menuperiod has multiple menus
- A menu belongs to a menuperiod [X]
- A menu is made of multiple meals
- A meal can be in multiple menus

[X] A menuperiod has a start and end date, but it's just a collection a menu's. It doesn't necessarily have to be one week, it can be 2 weeks, couple of days, etc.. (e.g. christmas time, events, etc.)

This setup makes it more performant if future features were ever to be required.

A menu happens on a specific day, we use a date & that date needs to be between the startdate and enddate of its MenuPeriod (associated with menuperiodid(FK)). This happens in your business logic. This setup also makes it easier to copy weekmenu's from one week to another.

A menu occurs either in the morning (breakfast), mid-day (lunch) or in the evening (supper).

Example: The menu for Tuesday's breakfast contains 3 meals (bacon and eggs, croissants & a salad).

But this setup makes it also easier to copy menu's. Example: Every morning we got bacon and eggs.

Also a meal can be in multiple menus for specific a specific duration.

So if you want to do like a pizzaweek or something, call me.

Hope this helps!

PS: For the actual column types, I leave that up to you.

Also menuperiod has a name, which is not really necessary unless you wanted to name your menuperiods, like 'chickenweek' or the famous 'pizzaweek'. But if its a pure calendar, you could print out your start and enddate as a string instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's given me an alternative approach to think about =)

Comment: @MartinDev , with pleasure. If it answers your question, mark it as accepted answer. If you have any other questions don't hesitate to ask ;)